# Error on first run of gclient sync --force on Ubuntu

Tags: webrtc

After installing all the required software in correct order on Ubuntu, I ran the following 2 commands

```
$ gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
$ gclient sync --force
```

Latter one took some time and downloaded trunk and chromium_deps folders, however, it gave the following errors

```
________ running '/usr/bin/python trunk/build/gyp_chromium --depth=trunk trunk/all.gyp -Dextra_gyp_flag=0' in '/home/sojharo/Data/server'
Updating projects from gyp files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: Point $JAVA_HOME or the java_home gyp variable to a directory containing include/jni.h!
gyp: Call to 'python -c "import os; dir=os.getenv('JAVA_HOME', '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun'); assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir, 'include/jni.h')), 'Point \$JAVA_HOME or the java_home gyp variable to a directory containing include/jni.h!'; print dir"' returned exit status 1. while trying to load trunk/all.gyp
Error: Command /usr/bin/python trunk/build/gyp_chromium --depth=trunk trunk/all.gyp -Dextra_gyp_flag=0 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/sojharo/Data/server
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java must be oracle jdk. Also make sure your **`PATH`** for JAVA_HOME is set

[Follow this link for instructions](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/)

Note:The link provided in this example for *`gclient config`* command is older one. 
Follow your link
***gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk***

Comment: I installed the Java from the given link. But it did not work and gave the same error.

Comment: Check java_home is set or not in /etc/profile it should be like
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-version
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-version
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
Also oracle jdk-6 sholuld be the version , 7 has some issues while developing android apps

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really worked. I have a little question here, why do we need to do all this? I mean after building the project, we get peerconnection_server and peerconnection_client beside other files. Can't we just use other servers for WebRTC web applications?

Comment: Link to linkedin. Not possible to see if you're not authenticated